# Tall legs VS Long legs

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Which one of these sentences is correct, and why?

-I have tall legs.

-I have long legs.

Comment: In American English, you can't contract _I have_ to _I've_ in the sense of 'I possess'; only when _have_ is an auxiliary, like _I've lived here all my life._

Comment: @JohnLawler   I really didn't  know that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long legs* is the more common usage. The phrase *tall legs* is used very rarely, as demonstrated by [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tall%20legs%2C%20long%20legs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctall%20legs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20legs%3B%2Cc0)

The word *tall* is reserved for measuring in the vertical direction. Even though legs are often vertical, they can certainly be horizontal as well, for example, when lying down. This same sort of argument can be made of ladders; however, the phrases *long ladder* and *tall ladder* occur with roughly the same frequency ([Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tall+ladder%2C+long+ladder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctall%20ladder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20ladder%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctall%20ladder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20ladder%3B%2Cc0) again). It seems that there is no definitive rule to decide between *tall* or *long*. But for *legs*, using *long* is certainly more conventional.

Comment: _Tall_ is used of free-standing objects such as a person, a building or a tree. A person is tall partly because they have long legs.

Answer (score -2):

As I see it, the problem isn't with tall versus long legs, but your omission of "got" when using the contraction. The correct form, without and with the contraction, respectively would be: "I have long legs/I've got long legs"...

I'm tall and I have long legs.

Comment: I've just noticed the "and why?" part of the query. Other than the basic obvious fact that the person is tall and the legs are long, I don't really see how "why" comes into the equation.

Comment: It sounds like a misspoken _I've got long legs_ because that's grammatical US English, but *_I've long legs_ is not.